# Laravel/Lumen: validating data for email already exist and general validation

Tags: validation, laravel, lumen

I am writing an API. I was wondering how could I return proper response.

- data is not valid (only if email aready exists)
- data is not valid (general validation errors)

Here is my code so far:

```
$data = Input::all();

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email'            => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'some_other_field' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // NOTE: using a or b, this are my custom methods
    a) return $this->existsResponse($data);
    b) return $this->badRequestResponse($data);
}
```

How could I figure out if email already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it like this.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = Input::all();

    // validating data

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email'            => 'required|email',
        'some_other_field' => 'required'
    ]); 

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $this->badRequestResponse($data);
    }

    // validating if resource exists

    $userExists = User::where('email', $request->email)->count();

    if($userExists) {
        return $this->existsResponse($data);
    }

    // inserting data

    $user = new User();

    $user->fill($data);
    $user->save();

    if($user->save()) {
        return $this->createdResponse($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the Validator Class. I think the Methods invalid() and valid() should be the right for you. This methods gives you an array of keys back.

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_invalid

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have tried invalid() method, this gives me email element in both cases. But not specifying why element is not valid. Any ideas more?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're trying to do two different types of validations, so it would make sense to use two different validators:

```
$data = $request->all();

// validate email
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->existsResponse($data);
}

// email valid, so validate other data
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'some_other_field' => 'required'
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->badRequestResponse($data);
}

// if here, all data is valid
```

Comment: Thak you for your effort but this is not my case. Somehow I need to determine why email is not valid.